# Having Error using devise and rails 3.2.0rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just upgraded to rails 3.2.0.rc1 and i tried signing it with devise and it worked very well but if i try signing in with an invalid account i get the following error message `undefined method split for :failure:Symbol`

this is my server report

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 170ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `split' for :failure:Symbol):
  devise (1.5.3) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:119:in `recall_app'
  devise (1.5.3) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:46:in `recall'
  devise (1.5.3) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:30:in `respond'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:199:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:242:in `block in action'
  devise (1.5.3) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:19:in `call'
  devise (1.5.3) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:19:in `call'
  devise (1.5.3) lib/devise/delegator.rb:5:in `call'
  warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:121:in `call_failure_app'
  warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:107:in `process_unauthenticated'
  warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:47:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
  rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.0.rc1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:395:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:63:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.0.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /home/rzaartz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
  /home/rzaartz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
  /home/rzaartz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rub/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (3.4ms)
  Rendered /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rub/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered /home/rzaartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rub/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (9.2ms)
```

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. Did you try posting this to devise's github?

Comment: just posted it on github